# If I remove Windows and install Ubuntu, will the network drivers get reinstalled or remain the same

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I have Windows 10 on my laptop and I'm facing severe problems with network connectivity. I wifi keeps going on and off. One possible solution that I can see is to switch to Ubuntu. But I want to understand if the network drivers will be reinstalled from fresh or not. If they do not get reinstalled they I might start facing the wifi problems again.

Comment: Drivers is the end-user name for *kernel modules* (the technical name), thus they relate verify specifically to the kernel in use. Windows uses a different kernel to Ubuntu (which uses the Linux kernel), and the release of Ubuntu will dictate which Linux kernel is to be used (though LTS releases have two kernel stack choices; GA or HWE).  Any change to the kernel requires new kernel modules (or *drivers* to non-technical *layman* terminology); and Ubuntu does **not** use a microsoft NT kernel.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 'live', booted from a USB pendrive without installing. This way you can find out, if it will solve your problems. - It is possible that your problems with network connectivity is caused by something else (not the network drivers in Windows), and in that case you might have similar problems with Ubuntu. Trying Ubuntu live you will also get a general experience (the look and feel) of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is like saying I have a Honda car. One of the tires leaks air and regularly goes flat. One possible solution that I can see is to switch to Toyota. But I want to understand if the Toyota will come with fresh tires or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network drivers are separate in Ubuntu and Windows. The drivers are not shared. To make sure your network card still works, boot into a live system and test it. Ubuntu ships most required drivers by default in the installation image.

You might not have the connectivity issues on Ubuntu since the drivers are written differently depending on operating system.

Comment: ... or you may find out you have the same problems in which case the cause isn't any OS, drivers or other software but something else in the network.